# Unity 2D Input Action not releasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, 2d

Am trying to add variable jump height to a platformer using Unity's new Input System. Since I'm trying to integrate a Finite State Machine Framework, I'm reading inputs using the Send Messages behaviour. To add the variable jump height, the following function is called in an Idle State when the jump action is pressed:

```
public void Jump(InputAction jumpAct)
    {
        float jumpCount = 10f;
        if (jumpAct.WasPressedThisFrame())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpPower);
        }
        while (jumpCount > 0f)
        {
            if (jumpAct.WasReleasedThisFrame() && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
            {
                Debug.Log("Yay");
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
            } else
            {
                Debug.Log(jumpAct.ReadValueAsObject());
            }
            jumpCount -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

It seems that, even when I release the button, the InputValue is still registered as On (the second if statement always fails and the debugger prints a value of 1 for the jumpAct value). No idea why this is happening despite looking at documentation and different forums. Some help would be appreciated.

An extra note: I know for a fact that this can be fixed by using callback contexts from the Invoke Unity Events behaviour. However, ideally there is a solution that uses the Send Messages behaviour, since I would otherwise need to rewrite a good chunk of the FSM framework I've coded.

have tried WasReleasedThisFrame(), !IsPressed(), and !WasPressedThisFrame(). Have tried adding and removing triggers to the InputAction on the character component. Have tried reading for the InputValue directly with ReadValueAsObject() instead of checking the above methods. The result stays the same. There is a jump, but the height is uniform regardless of when the button is released.

An extra update. I have found a way to read the callback context phase of the action. The entire time, this phase is read as "performed", even when the button is released.

Comment: i confess Ive not tried doing that, i have used the  action.IsPressed, and the performed and cancelled events, but not like this.  given the while loop im not sure how frame portion works with that.  it looks like as long as the button is released in 10s it will halv the jump speed..

Comment: @BugFinder the entire `while` loops is being executed within a single frame ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your entire `while` loop will be executed within one single frame and your release condition can never be met except you really smash and release the button so fast that it is both pressed and released within the same frame.

Assuming you are calling this method each frame anyway e.g. from `Update` - otherwise you would simply use the event driven approach - you only need to handle **one single frame** at a time and do e.g.

```
private float jumpCount = 10f;

public void Jump(InputAction jumpAct)
{
    if (jumpAct.WasPressedThisFrame())
    {
        jumpCount = 10f;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpPower);
    }

    // NOTE: "if" instead of "while" -> only one single execution at a time
    if(jumpCount > 0f)
    {
        jumpCount -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (jumpAct.WasReleasedThisFrame() && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("Yay");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        } 
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(jumpAct.ReadValueAsObject());
        }
    }
}
```

I would probably still use the event driven approach anyway and do something like e.g.

```
// in your state enter method
YourActionMap.jump.performed += StartJump;
YourActionMap.jump.canceled += StopJump;


// accordingly in your state exit method
YourActionMap.jump.performed -= StartJump;
YourActionMap.jump.canceled -= StopJump;
```

and then

```
private float jumpStartTime;

private void StartJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpPower);
    jumpStartTime = Time.time;
}

private void StopJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if(Time.time - jumpStartTime <= 10f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the method is not called repeatedly in an Update() method. It is called once when a jump press is recognised in the Idle State, and then the state is exited from and the jumping state is immediately entered. Even if that was not the case, the jumpCount would keep resetting every time the method is called. The while loop was to try to force the method to exist over multiple frames; is there a better way to force that behaviour?

Comment: Oh whoops. I didn't notice the event-driven approach. I gave that implementation a whirl and I'm getting the same issue. The action is registered as "performed" but never "cancelled"

Comment: I've managed to resolve the issue. Basically the jumping script was being exited out of before the InputAction could ever be registered as cancelled because the idle state transitioned to the jumping state that very frame. All I had to do was split up the method into a performed and a cancelled method, then move the logic into the jumping state, and leave the performed section within the state Enter() method, while the cancelled section could exist as an event method